# Yii2 urlManager создание правильной ссылки

Tags: yii2

Всех приветствую. В файле web.php для rules написано следующая правила:

```
'volunteer/' => '/volunteer/volunteer/index',
'volunteer/photos/' => '/volunteer/volunteer/photos',
'volunteer/<id:\d+>' => '/volunteer/volunteer/index',
```

ссылку создаю так:

```
    <a href="<?= Url::to(['/volunteer', 'id' =>Yii::$app->user->getId() ]) ?>" >
     <?= Yii::t('app/menus', 'Моя страница') ?>
    </a>
```

Мне надо получит ссылку типа /volunteer/123  а получается volunteer?id=123
Что делаю не так?
Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 0):

неверный роут, должно быть 'volunteer/volunteer/index' вместо '/volunteer'. см.примеры в руководстве https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/runtime-routing#creating-urls

Comment: не помог. Документацию читал, просто понят не могу что не так

Comment: туплю, если http сервер настроен верно(rewrite rules), то добавь 'urlManager' => ['enablePrettyUrl' => true, 'showScriptName' => false,] в раздел components конфига приложения

Comment: Подозреваю это из-за того, что контроллер volunteer находится в controllers/volunteer/VolunteerController.  Для других контроллеров находящих в controllers все работает

Comment: сложно сказать не видя кода приложения, попробуйте крайние слеши убрать, возможно стоит режим строгой проверки